# How to build an undo storage with limit?

Tags: python, storage, undo, fifo

I want build a data structure to store limited undo buffer, take store 6 dict data for example with below pseudocode:

```
rawdict1 = {1}
buffer = [{1}]

rawdict1 = {2}
buffer = [{2}{1}]      # {1} stored on the postion

rawdict1 = {3}
buffer = [{3}{2}{1}]      
...
rawdict1 = {5}
buffer = [{5}{4}{3}{2}{1}]      # max length limited to 5

rawdict1 = {6}
buffer = [{6}{5}{4}{3}{2}]      # {1} has been deleted because exceed the limit

when I want to restore the rawdict1 later, I can use something looks like:

rawdict1 = buffer[5]                 # restore the 5th dict.
```

My question is, can existing buildin data type or standard library type can be used for such a purpose?

And is it possible such a structure can store multi-types in one structure instance, say, if I want to store dict and self-defined class in one go?

Thanks!

Rgs,

KC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use something like this:

```
import collections

class UndoBuffer(object):
    def __init__(self,value,max_length=5):
        self.max_length=max_length
        self._buffer=collections.deque([value],max_length)
    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._buffer[-1]
    @data.setter
    def data(self,value):
        self._buffer.append(value)
    def restore(self,index):
        self.data=self._buffer[index]
```

Make an UndoBuffer object

```
rawdict=UndoBuffer('{1}')
```

Setting the `data` attribute automatically stores the value in `_buffer`:

```
print(rawdict._buffer)
# deque(['{1}'], maxlen=5)
print(rawdict.data)
# {1}
```

Changing the value of `rawdict.data` appends the value to `rawdict._buffer`:

```
rawdict.data = '{2}'
print(rawdict._buffer)
# deque(['{1}', '{2}'], maxlen=5)
```

Buf if you access `rawdict.data` you just get the most recent value:

```
print(rawdict.data)
# {2}
```

Change the value a few more times. '{1}' gets dropped when the buffer is filled to its maximum length:

```
rawdict.data = '{3}'
rawdict.data = '{4}'
rawdict.data = '{5}'
print(rawdict._buffer)
# deque(['{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}'], maxlen=5)
rawdict.data = '{6}'
print(rawdict._buffer)
# deque(['{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}'], maxlen=5)
```

Restoring the value from rawdict._buffer:

```
rawdict.restore(0)   # set rawdict.data to rawdict._buffer[0]
print(rawdict.data)
# {2}
print(rawdict._buffer)
# deque(['{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}', '{2}'], maxlen=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it on a barename (such as `rawdict1`) because there is no way for you to intercept assignments to a barename and make them do sometime "on the side" such as saving the previous value.  It's easy to do on a *decorated* name, e.g.:

```
undoable.rawdict1 = {1}
```

and the like, by making `undoable` an instance of a class with an appropriate `__setitem__` which appends the previous value (if any) to a list, and pops the 0th item if the list is getting too long.  But that would not suffice for *other* "undoable" actions besides assignment, such as `undoable.rawdict1.update(whatever)` -- you sure you don't need that?

Comment: I think you went two steps beyond what the OP needed here. :-)
I,for myself, will remember this answer when a "undoable" class decorator might be handy! :-)

Comment: thanks Alex, glad to see you give answer again. Maybe not a container class with a build-in undo action here, I want a container as a flange for the data stream with undo capabilitiy: it may looks like this: data_consumers <=> undo_container <=> data_source *** data_consumers may change the data_source if I operated on the data_source directly given no change to restore it, then I need a buffer and undo opportunity here. and the rawdata1 is the data from external, maybe I have to make a deepcopy then push them into the undo class?

Comment: @Registered, if you can do the pushing as an explicit action at any given, significant point of your choice, instead of having done it implicitly by assignments to an undoable barename, your life is definitely going to be simpler;-).

Comment: noted it, thanks Alex, I know I am the beginner for the programming then I still need guys help here expecially on those basic part I can understand easily ;-).

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly subclass the list to only allow limited storage.

```
class LimitedStack(list):
 def __init__(self,limit=6):
    list.__init__(self)
    self.limit = limit

 def append(self,obj):
    if len(self) == self.limit:
        list.pop(self,0)
    list.append(self,obj)
```

Python lists do not have to be of a certain type like the generic lists in C#. They will store any object you append to them.

Answer (score 1):

The collections module, as of python 2.6, contains the "deque" collection. It behaves as you  need:

```
>>> import collections
>>> buffer = collections.deque([],6)
>>> buffer.extend(range(6))
>>> buffer
deque([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], maxlen=6)
>>> buffer.append(6)
>>> buffer
deque([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], maxlen=6)
>>> buffer[-1]
6
```

Answer (score 0):

[Rockford Lhotka's CSLA.NET framework](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/) contains an Undo architecture.  Perhaps you could study it and figure out what he did, or even use it out of the box.

Comment: however it may a bit big for me for my quick solution. I just need a storage may store 5 copies of the raw data and assign index for them.